# Why is MapBox lagging in Unity VR?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying out the MapBox SDK for Unity.

https://www.mapbox.com/unity/

- This provides a 2D map where you can zoom in and out to preview
  different levels of detail.This honestly works like a charm.
- I am trying to get this 2D map working in Virtual Reality.
- The only problem is that it is lagging since the VR camera moves a
  lot.

I am using either **SteamVR Player** or **CameraRig**.

Does someone know how to improve the MapBox performance for Virtual Reality?

At this point, my unity is just freezing.

I am looking forward for any advice / insight

Comment: have you tried looking into it with the Profiler? you can try to narrow it down a bit

Comment: Thanks for the reaction. What do you mean with the Profiler? At this point, I am only using an empty GameObject that I have called "Map". On this GameObject, I have put the Abstract Map script. This provides the satellite map.

Comment: if you go Window/Profiler it opens a Profiles, you can select to record 'Deep Profile' which will slow down your code by half, but you'll get a detailed footprint of the code - how much it spends doing a given operation, so you can try to nail it down to computational complexity / ram usage / Garbage collection / gpu etc

Comment: Okay I found it. All I can figure out is that it is very heavy for my computer when I am moving the camera: https://imgur.com/CzX2wZg

Comment: if (and I would assume so) its the MapBox consuming all those cycles you might have to write some kind of caching layer or something, probably far from trivial